# How can I make the the google chart animation start only when it comes into view when scrolled?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hi I want to know how can I make the google chart animation only start when scrolled and when it comes into view.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>


google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMultSeries);

function drawMultSeries() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', '2010 Population', '2000 Population'],
    ['New York City, NY', 8175000, 8008000],
    ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000, 3694000],
    ['Chicago, IL', 2695000, 2896000],
    ['Houston, TX', 2099000, 1953000],
    ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000, 1517000]
  ]);

 var options = {  
              animation: {
            duration: 2000,
            startup: true //This is the new option
        },
           };  

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Use intersection observer and only init the chart when in view https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a listener on scroll and only load google chart on condition ("when the user scroll pass #chart_div") :

```
let alreadyLoaded = false ;     
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
if (alreadyLoaded === false){

        var element = document.querySelector('#chart_div');
        var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    
        if(position.top >= 0 && position.bottom <= window.innerHeight) {

    
        // checking for partial visibility
        if(position.top < window.innerHeight && position.bottom >= 0) {
    alreadyLoaded = true;  
       google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMultSeries);
    
    function drawMultSeries() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City', '2010 Population', '2000 Population'],
        ['New York City, NY', 8175000, 8008000],
        ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000, 3694000],
        ['Chicago, IL', 2695000, 2896000],
        ['Houston, TX', 2099000, 1953000],
        ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000, 1517000]
      ]);
    
     var options = {  
                  animation: {
                duration: 2000,
                startup: true //This is the new option
            },
               };  
    
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
      }
}
     });
```

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm, however when I scroll back again the animation starts over. Is there any way to make the animation only play once after scrolled into view and not play again until the page is refreshed? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Sure you just have to create a boolean (true/false) and track when the script load the first time ! (I've updated my post adding this)

Comment: Thanks for replying and editing the code. The code does work, the animation does not play more than once. However, the chart only gets visible if its like a small scroll away. For example, when I'm on top of the page and when the chart is on bottom, if I am to scroll all the way to the bottom, the chart won't be visible, it will be missing until the page is refreshed. This was not the case in the previous code provided. The previous code worked 100%, only played animations more than once if I'm to scroll. Is there any solution to this? Thank you in advance.